# Должен ли тестировщик знать unit-test фреймворки?

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование

Должен ли тестировщик знать `unit-test фреймворки`? Я не говорю про ручное тестирование. Меня интерсует автоматизация. `Конкретно - junit/TestNG`.

И тут же про Selenium - кто пишет тесты в нем, разработчик или тестер? Юнит-тесты должны писаться разработчиками, верно?

Вопрос родился из-за [этого](http://habrahabr.ru/post/145974/#habracut) поста на хабре. Времени тестировщики переписывали автоматические тесты, чтобы они соответствовали текущему набору функций системы. Т.е. это была работа ради самих тестов."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должен ли тестировщик знать unit-test фреймворки? - да

И тут же про Selenium - кто пишет тесты в нем, разработчик или тестер? - Программист либо опытный тестер, который хочет упростить для себя задачу (т.е автоматизация тестирования).

Юнит-тесты должны писаться разработчиками, верно? - Если юнит-тесты - это часть requirements, то это задача программиста. Он пишет приложение и он пишет тест-кейсы. Другое дело, что эти тест кейсы зачастую программисты пишут только для того, чтоб от них отстали.

Личный опыт: видел я селениумм тест кейсы, которые писали тестеры, лучше б не видеть, - я б такой код стеснялся кому-то показывать. Ведь помимо того, чтоб закодить логику тестирования, надо еще и язык знать и уметь программировать. Вот последнего тестерам часто не хватает. Хотя я уверен, что опытному тестеру, который постоянно занимается автоматизацией тестирования, эта задача по зубам.